# python3-config --ldflags doesn't include -lpython3.x

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, linux, compiler-errors

## Problem statement

When trying to build a sample Cython application with g++, I get the linker error `undefined reference to 'Py_Finalize'`. The Python linker arguments are provided by `python3-config`, but they appear to be incomplete. If I additionally include `-lpython3.x`, the build succeeds and the binary runs.

## Reproduction

To reproduce the problem, I created a minimal (not) working example with Docker. The file that I want to compile is `main.cpp` and looks like this:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  std::cout << "Python initialized" << std::endl;
  Py_Finalize();
}
```

The corresponding `Dockerfile` is the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential python3.10 libpython3.10 python3-dev libpython3-dev

COPY main.cpp /root
RUN g++ -g $(python3-config --cflags) /root/main.cpp $(python3-config --ldflags) -o /root/main
```

My system is Ubuntu 22.04 (but 20.04 exhibits the same problem) and Python 3.10 (but 3.8 and 3.9 exhibits the same problem).

## Observations

The build log is the following:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN g++ -g $(python3-config --cflags) /root/main.cpp $(python3-config --ldflags) -o /root/main
 ---> Running in b60bbdb5d14f
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccU46Ddl.o: in function `main':
/root/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The command '/bin/sh -c g++ -g $(python3-config --cflags) /root/main.cpp $(python3-config --ldflags) -o /root/main' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It's missing `Py_Initialize` and `Py_Finalize`, i.e., those symbols from the Python3 library. The output of `python3-config --ldflags` is:

```
-L/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -lcrypt -ldl  -lm -lm
```

If I manually add the `-lpython3.10` option, the build succeeds:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN g++ -g $(python3-config --cflags) /root/main.cpp $(python3-config --ldflags) -lpython3.10 -o /root/main && /root/main
 ---> Running in c2551fbfa979
Python initialized
Removing intermediate container c2551fbfa979
 ---> 47303fef29ad
Successfully built 47303fef29ad
```

The output of `python3-config --ldflags` on Debian and Python 3.7 (Docker image `python:3.7-slim`) *does* include `lpython3.7m`:

```
$ docker run -it python:3.7-slim python3-config --ldflags
 -L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.7m -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
```

On Debian with Python 3.10 (Docker image `python:3.10-slim`), we can observe this problem as well:

```
$ docker run -it python:3.10-slim python3-config --ldflags
 -L/usr/local/lib  -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -lm
```

## Questions

1. Why doesn't `python3-config` give me all necessary linker options to build this application?
2. Am I supposed to add `-lpython3.10` by myself or are there better ways (i.e., more system-independent ways) to circumvent this?
3. Is the output of `python3-config` erroneous and why does it include `-lm` twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having checked the source code of `python3-config`, it became clear to me that the (undocumented) option `--embed` is required for this flag to be included, for example:

```bash
$ python3-config --ldflags --embed
-L/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.10 -lcrypt -ldl  -lm -lm
```

This was introduced in Python 3.8, and information on this is detailed in the [description of changes of Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#debug-build-uses-the-same-abi-as-release-build).

Furthermore, `lm` is included twice because the LIBS and SYSLIBS configuration variables both include it.